# Understanding the update rule for the policy in the policy iteration algorithm

Tags: reinforcement-learning, value-iteration, policy-iteration, policy-improvement

Consider the grid world problem in RL. Formally, policy in RL is defined as $\pi(a|s)$. If we are solving grid world by policy iteration then the following pseudocode is used:

[image]

My question is related to the policy improvement step. Specifically, I am trying to understand the following update rule.

$$\pi(s) \leftarrow arg max_a \sum_{s'}p(s'|s,a)[r(s,a,s') + \gamma v(s')] $$

I can have 2 interpretations of this update rule.

1. In this step, we check which action (say, going right for a particular state) has the highest reward and assign going right a probability of 1 and rest actions a probability of 0. Thus, in PE step, we will always go right for all iterations for that state even if it might not be the most rewarding function after certain iterations.
2. We keep the policy improvement step in mind, and, while doing the PE step, we update the $v(s)$, based on the action giving highest reward (say, for 1st iteration $k=0$, going right gives the highest reward, we update based on that, while, for $k=1$, we see going left gives the highest reward, and update our value based on that likewise. Thus action changes depending on maximum reward).

For me, the second interpretation is very similar to value iteration. So, which one is the correct interpretation of a policy iteration?

Comment: Your first interpretation is correct, in policy evaluation step, every loop iteration you act considering the current fixed policy that you think is the best, that policy may not be the overall best policy, but currently we think it is. You learn about how good that policy is by updating values (while acting according to our current policy) and then you improve it in policy improvement step based on those values that you got in PE step.

Comment: @Brale_ The first interpretation is wrong. You don't necessarily always go "right" for all iterations of a single PE step. The greedy action might change, after each PE step. I also clarify in my answer that the greedy action might not be the same for all states, so you don't necessarily go "right" for all states (during a single run of PE or, equivalently, for different iterations of the same PI step).

Comment: @nbro greedy action changes after policy improvement step (hence the name improvement), in policy evaluation you evaluate your current policy, action that you choose for specific state doesn't change in every loop iteration of policy evaluation step

Comment: @Brale_ Yes, even though there might not be a strict improvement for all states in PI. However, note that in the OP stated "Thus in PE step we will always go right for all iterations even if it might not be the most rewarding function after certain iterations.". To me this seems to imply that $\pi(s)$ is "right" for all states, but this is not necessarily the case. Maybe I am just wrongly interpreting this statement, which is ambiguous.

Comment: there might be a misunderstanding, I thought the OP was saying that we act according to our current policy in states, obviously if an action for $s_1$ is going right it would be incorrect going right in $s_2$, unless that is the greedy action for that state

Comment: @nbro I meant for a particular state not all states, if it was ambiguous previously.

Comment: @Brale_ no I meant right for a single state only, it maybe clearer from my comments below the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A policy can be stochastic or deterministic. A deterministic policy is a function of the form $\pi_{\text{deterministic}}: S \rightarrow A$, that is, a function from the set of states to the set of actions. A stochastic policy is a map of the form $\pi_{\text{stochastic}} : S \rightarrow P(A)$, where $P(A)$ is a set of probability distributions ($P(A) = \{ p_{s_1}(A), p_{s_2}(A), \dots, p_{s_{|S|}}(A) \}$, where $p_{s_i}(A)$ is a probability distribution over the set of actions $A$ for the state $s_i$ and $|S|$ is the size of the set of states of the environment) over the set of actions $A$. A deterministic policy can be interpreted as a stochastic policy that gives the probability of $1$ to one of the available actions (and $0$ to the remaining actions), for each state.

In the case of value iteration (VI) and policy iteration (PI), the policy is deterministic, both in the policy evaluation (PE) or policy improvement (PI) steps.

In the PE step, for a **specific** state $s$ (inside the for loop), you use $\pi(s)$, that is, you assume that the action taken in the *specific* state $s$ is the greedy action, because of the $\text{argmax}$ in the PI, according to the current policy. However, in general, $\pi_k(s_i) \neq \pi_k(s_j)$, for $i \neq j$, where $k$ is the current iteration step (of PE and PI).

The update rule

$$\pi_{k+1}(s) \leftarrow arg max_a \sum_{s'}p(s' \mid s, a)[r(s, a, s') + \gamma v_k(s')]$$

computes the action that is **expected** to give the highest return, given the current and fixed value function $(v_k$). Have a look at the definition of [expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) for discrete random variables: it is defined as a weighted sum (like in the update rule above, where the weights are $p(s' \mid s, a)$).

Value iteration is a shorter version of policy iteration. In VI, rather than performing a PI step for each state of the environment, when performing PE, the action that is *expected* to give the highest return is chosen. In VI, the policy is updated only once and at the end of policy evaluation. In PI, you alternate between PE and PI, and, at each PI, you update the policy.

Comment: So the main question is the probablity assigned during the Pimprovement step or Pevaluation step? If you see that was the two of my interpretations. Basically if you use tensorflow then you'll know in it we don't explicitly define any data, but we just build a model. So is the policy an explicit definition of probablity or is it a rule which is used in PE step (I.e act greedily).

Comment: Thus would the probablity be already assigned before the beginning of **PE step** or would it be assigned for each **PE iteration**?

Comment: @DuttaA When you perform one PE step, the policy is fixed (so the probabilities for that specific PE step have already been assigned). When you perform the next PE step, the policy is also fixed, but it might be different than the fixed policy you used in the previous PE step (because, during PI, you change the policy).

Comment: so basically a policy  in a policy evaluation step is a fixed set of probabilities instead of a abstract command 'act greedily' for each state.

Comment: @DuttaA Given that the policy used in this context is deterministic, it might not be convenient to think of probabilities. However, the policy you use in PE is fixed (as I said above). This fixed policy used in PE has been computed using a "greedy" method in PI, so I would think of the fixed policy used in PE as a greedy policy with respect to the previous value function. I think this diagram might help: [http://incompleteideas.net/book/first/ebook/node46.html](http://incompleteideas.net/book/first/ebook/node46.html). It gives you the idea behind policy iteration.

Comment: thanks...So that basically is the difference between VI and PI, acting greedily in VI ensures you are always going towards better which might not be true in PI.

Comment: @DuttaA I would think of the difference between PI and VI as follows. $PI: E \rightarrow I \rightarrow E \rightarrow I \rightarrow E \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow I$ and $VI: E \rightarrow E \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow E \rightarrow I$, where $I$ means improvement of the policy and $E$ means evaluation of the current fixed policy (that is, update of the current value function given the current fixed policy).

Comment: @DuttaA policy iteration and value iteration are basically the same thing. Value iteration is a special case of policy iteration where you do a single step of policy evaluation (no for loop for $n$ steps, only a single step) and after that policy improvement, while in policy iteration you do policy evaluation for $n$ steps (for loop with $n$ steps) and then policy improvement. Also, in value iteration policy improvement is sort of implicit, its "blended" in in policy evaluation step.

Comment: @nbro but in VI the policy is 'act greedily' (probablities will be decided based on which state gives max reward) whereas in Piteration, improvement step passes a fixed set of probabilities (deterministic upto my knowledge) upon which evaluation is acted upon.

Comment: @DuttaA Yes, in VI one can think of it as acting greedily, because of the $\max$. In PI, you explicitly use the policy $\pi$. In VI, in the policy evaluation step, you do not explicitly use the actual policy $\pi$. You use a $\max$. This max can be interpreted as if we were using a greedy policy, but I am not sure this is a good idea.